# How to detect the end of the FaceID animation?

Tags: ios, swift, face-id

I need to display a popup right after a successful FaceID authentication, but the FaceID callback is triggered before the animation's end.
How to know for sure when the animation is finished?

Comment: FaceID seems to a consistent animation -- you could put a timer after callback completion to match the animation end.

Comment: @rohanphadte That is what I currently do, as a temporary fix. I hope there is a cleaner way!